# Cant locate by xpath because its the Xpath is always changing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I Tried to locate the input element below (also in the picture), by its content: [image]

```
<input _ngcontent-c39="" autocomplete="off" class="remove-input-styling mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" matinput="" readonly="true" ng-reflect-owl-date-time="[object Object]" ng-reflect-min="Thu Jun 20 2019 09:38:58 GMT+0" ng-reflect-select-mode="range" ng-reflect-readonly="" ng-reflect-dt-picker="[object Object]" aria-haspopup="true" min="2019-06-20T06:38:58.206Z" id="mat-input-23" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

1.Tried that -

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(.,'remove-input-styling mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched')]")
```

and

2. Tried that -

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='remove-input-styling mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][contains(.,' ')]")))
```

This is the executing line:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", self.date_element)
```

Both ways I tried about didn't find the x-path

Comment: _Both ways I tried_ Do you see any error?

Comment: what is changing ? It has id. You can try with find by id.

Comment: The error is that it's not finding it, I think I should write it differently but I couldn't figure how. maybe something in the parenthesis in adding or not adding

Comment: The meaning of changing is that the Xpath could be: //*[@id="mat-input-6"]   or   //*[@id="mat-input-5"] or other possibe forms

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Xpath?

```
//input[contains(@id,'mat-input')]
```

Comment: that how i implement you help:        
date_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'mat-input')]")


self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", date_element)

                      
That is the error i got:                

 selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64)